# Add space between curly brackets using regex

Tags: regex

I would like to add a space before & after all curly brackets in my project.

Example:

```
item: {id: 3, name: 'Gina'}
should become
item: { id: 3, name: 'Gina' }
```

Using VSCode, I can get the text between usign `{.*}`, what do I replace it with so I earn the format I want?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with VSCode, but here's the general solution:

```
Match: <space>?[{}]<space>?
Replace: <space>$0<space>
```

Where `<space>` is a space character.

`$0` is a *back reference* to the entire match, which will be either `{` or `}`.

The optional spaces (followed by `?`) in the match will consume any spaces that may be there, thus preventing double spaces from being in the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can find `{(.*?)}` // where your content is in group 1

and

replace with `{ $1 }` // add space and then the captured group

Answer (score 1):

We would simply capture our inputs using:

```
(.+?\{)(.*)(\})
```

or

```
(.+?\{)(.*?)(\})
```

and replace it with:

```
$1 $2 $3
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HSe8KZ/1)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, we can modify/change it in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HSe8KZ/1/).